# Spree Commerce Number of Products in a Taxon | Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, e-commerce, spree

I'm new to spree commerce and doing come customizations.

I have some category Taxons displaying on the homepage (i.e. T-Shirts). I want to be able to display the count for the number of products in this category (i.e. T-Shirts, 20 products).

From the documentation, I believe this should work:

`<%= Spree::Product.taxons_name_eq("t-shirts").all.count %> PRODUCTS`

But I just get {} Products as an output.

Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 0):

The following should work for you:

```
Spree::Taxon.where(name: 't-shirts').products.count
```

and let me know if you have problem with it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I get an undefined method for products error.

Comment: I have found this but not sure how to apply: https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/spree_core/1.0.3/Spree/Taxon#active_products-instance_method

Answer (score 0):

You can first find the `Taxon` with the name "t-shirts" then count the number of products associated with that taxon. This code, or something similar should do it:

```
Spree::Taxon.where(name: 't-shirts').first.products.count
```